# Automatically Login on Debian 9.2.1 Command Line

Tags: debian, login, autologin

I just installed Debian 9.2.1 on an old laptop as a cheap server. The computer is not physically accessed by anyone other than myself, so I would like to automatically login upon startup so that if I have to use the laptop itself rather than SSH, I don't have to bother logging in. I have no graphical environments installed, so none of those methods would work, and I've tried multiple solutions such as https://superuser.com/questions/969923/automatic-root-login-in-debian-8-0-console-only
However all it did was result in no login prompt being given at all... So I reinstalled Debian.
What can I do to automatically log in without a graphical environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` , change `#NAutoVTs=6` to `NAutoVTs=1`

Create a `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf` through ;

```bsh
systemctl edit getty@tty1
```

Paste the following lines

```bsh
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin root --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

enable the `getty@tty1.service` then reboot

```bsh
systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
reboot
```

[Arch linux docs :getty](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/getty)

Comment: I must have done something wrong, because this broke my system: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466088/37050. Worthwhile to check out depending on the answers there.

Comment: Definitely worked for me, after checking for typos... Thanks

Comment: This seems to work on Debian Buster as well

Comment: Adding to Jonathan Holvey's comment: and in Raspbian (Buster), this comes pretty close to how raspi-config does it when you use it to set auto console login. The main difference is the account name, it uses the current user account (the one running 'sudo raspi-config', so it's not necessarily 'pi') instead of root. Running it from a root shell (sudo -i) does not make it use the root account either. Secondary difference is that it doesn't include a baud rate.

Answer (score 10):

I just want to add to this discussion that the accepted answer pertains to virtual terminals. In my case, I had to edit a separate service file which is used for serial terminals. The file is found at `/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` and the same procedure of adding `--autologin <user>` to the appropriate line does the trick.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 --autologin root %I $TERM
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to add a slightly more thorough answer, especially given the comment about breaking his system from @Keelan.

First if you wish to only have one TTY that is running the program, and not be able to log in to any other tty, THEN edit your `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, and change `#NAutoVTs=6` to `NAutoVTs=1`. Doing this will keep you from logging in on the terminal!

Next create a directory and an `override.conf` file:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
echo "[Service]" > /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
echo "ExecStart=" >> /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
echo "ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin root --noclear %I 38400 linux" >> /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
```

**Don't reboot.** Instead of rebooting, as described in the other answer, log in to another TTY, then run the following commands to test things out:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart getty@tty1.service
```

If all goes well, then reboot.

**But what if I want to run a program instead of autologin?**
Then you would use the following:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d
echo "[Service]" > /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
echo "ExecStart=" >> /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
echo "ExecStart=-/path/program -arg1 -arg2" >> /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
echo "StandardInput=tty"  >> /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
echo "StandardOutput=tty"  >> /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
```

Now keep in mind this will run without a `bashrc`. This means if you use something like `screen` then you won't get all your usual aliases/etc. To fix that, use the standard auto-login above, but add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
[ `tty` == /dev/tty1 ] && /path/program -arg1 -arg2
```

This means that the program will only be run on `tty1`, but will give you a full shell underneath.