# tty1 missing login prompt

Tags: debian, login, tty, getty, agetty

I have a clean Debian Stretch installation. It used to be the case that after booting I would end up on tty1 with a login prompt, and after logging X is started. I wanted to automate the logging in (because I'm the only user and my disk is encrypted already) so I followed the exact instructions given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401798/37050):

- In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, changed `#NAutoVTs=6` to `NAutoVTs=1`
- Used `systemctl edit getty@tty1` and added (where `username` is my username):

  ```
  [Service]
  ExecStart=
  ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin username --noclear %I 38400 linux
  ```
- Enabled the service: `systemctl enable getty@tty1.service`

After rebooting, the login prompt was gone from tty1 and nothing else happened. It still showed the boot log. On tty2-5, only a cursor appeared, no login prompt as before. Luckily, tty6 was still available to recover the system. So I did:

- Disable the service: `systemctl disable getty@tty1.service`
- Undid the change to `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Now, I can use all ttys except tty1 to login as normally, but somehow tty1 remains damaged. How can I repair this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable the `getty@tty1.service` again:

```
systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
```

Comment: I'm on Arch Linux where I also have a disabled tty1. I tried the above instructions, but it doesn't enable tty1 for me.