# Debian Stretch auto login on boot

Tags: boot, autologin, getty

I am trying to figure out how to get automatic login to work with a base console installation of Debian Stretch testing

I tried an answer to a similar question on this site but it did not work:

[Automatically Login on Debian 9.2.1 Command Line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401759/automatically-login-on-debian-9-2-1-command-line)

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: * note: testing is not stretch, nor 'buster-beta', it's exactly called Buster nowadays.

Comment: Didn't realize it was out - updating post