# Openbox autostart do with big delay or until user made any action

Tags: debian, openbox, autostart

I have autologin with lightdm and i make some command to run automatically in openbox autostart, but it not work until i click mouse/keyboard/touchscreen

Also i check sometime it started after few minutes (around 1 minute 35 seconds, 00:02:15, e.t.c.)

OS: Debian 10
installed packages: lightdm, openbox, xorg

Comment: Get rid of lightdm, just use openbox and put `exec openbox-session` in your  `$HOME/.xintrc`, then use `startx` when you want a GUI.

Comment: I remove: apt remove lightdm, then create new not exist file $HOME/.xintrc and add command exec openbox-session, but still not work

Comment: do: `sudo apt install openbox obconf menu` then try again.  (for more info look at https://wiki.debian.org/Openbox). Alternatively there must be something wrong in our `autostart`, add a copy to your question

Comment: Something wrong with last remove ligtdm. Now i remove end get console on boot. But i need autologin and autostart openbox

Comment: I do autologin to console like describe here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401759/automatically-login-on-debian-9-2-1-command-line and then do startx in ~/.profile

But problem is still there, need to wait some time or do intput user action.

Comment: I have the same problem. Is your CPU is AMD?
It seems to me that autologin normally work (without delay), but does not start the X-server until you press a few keys.

Comment: I have CPU is Intel

Answer (score 0):

See: [autologin](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=102366) and [xinit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Boot)

also look at [this](https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=5544) (ignore that the title says "without display manager")

Comment: Autologin for now work, problem with big delay my application in autostart of openbox