# starting into program instead into login

Tags: debian, login, proxmox

I have a Proxmox 6.2 HV (based on Debian10) in my chamber.

I would like to see BPYTOP instead of the login-prompt on my direclty to the server attached monitor. If bpytop is closed, the login-prompt should appear.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

bpytop runs in the user world, so it needs to be run by a user.  I would create a system user for this.  If you don't give this system user sudo rights, then it's pretty limited in what it can do with this password-less scenario.  Instead of using a conventional shell, I'd set this user to run bpytop.

```
adduser --system --shell $(which bpytop) bpytop-monitor
```

Now when you `sudo su bpytop-monitor`, bpytop will start running.  When you exit out of bpytop, the user will log out.

Next we need to automatically log-in as `bpytop-monitor` when the machine boots.  There have already been some answers on this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/488003/272848), so I'm going to paraphrase/customize:

---

Stuff below this line I haven't tested.  Consider trying this in a VM or using a backup in case this prevents you from accessing your machine.

---

Edit your `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, change `#NAutoVTs=6` to `NAutoVTs=1`

Create `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf` through:

```
systemctl edit getty@tty1
```

Paste the following lines

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin bpytop-monitor --noclear %I $TERM
```

Enable `getty@tty1.service` then reboot

```
systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
reboot
```

Comment: Great work, thanks a lot. BUT: If I close bpytop (Strg+C) it restarts instead of login-screen. Can this be improved?

Comment: Hmmm, I think I see what's happening.  `getty@.service` contains `Restart=always`.  When you logged out, I expected it to be at the login prompt, but it appears that getty itself exits, then systemd restarts the service per `Restart=always`, giving you the loop.  What happens if you CTRL+ALT+F2?  If that works, you could reserve TTY1 for this monitor, then TTY2+ for normal user logins.

Comment: Sadly, Strg+Alt+F2 doesn't anything .